# File handling class object

Tags: c++

This is a C++ program for implementing offline messaging system. First a user has to register for an account by choosing a username and password. Then they can send and receive messages to other users.

I have written the program but there appears to be some logical errors.

I write the user details into a file email upon registration. Data is written into files as objects.

Suppose I registered 3 accounts. but I can't sign in IE. I can't verify login and pass control to `signin()`;

To troubleshoot the error I have created a `print()` function that displays content of file email.

I have placed this just before login authenticating part to see if data records are present

However records are not being displayed.

I can't test other portion of the code until I solve this.

Partial code that I think is the possible cause of error:

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int user;           // to keep a track of no. of users

class mail
{
public:
    char un[25];             // user name
    char pd[25];             // passsword
    int ino;                 // no. of inbox messages
    int sno;                 //no.of sent messags
    char isbj[25][25];
    char ssbj[25][25];
    char imsg[25][50];
    char smsg[25][50];       // character array to store inbox and sent messages respecvly
    void reg();             // func to sign up
    void signin();
    mail()
    {
    }
    ~mail()
    {
    }
};

void print();
void print()                     // for testing purpose. retrieving data in the file
{
    mail o;
    cout<<"\nRunning print func();";

    ifstream filein;
    filein.open("email",ios::in|ios::binary);
    if(!filein)
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open file to read\n";
    }
    else
    {
        filein.seekg(0);
        filein.read((char *)&o,sizeof(o));
        while(filein)
        {
            puts(o.un);
            puts(o.pd);
            cout<<o.ino<<"  "<<o.sno;
            filein.read((char *)&o,sizeof(o));
        }
        getch();
    }
}


void mail::reg()                      // sign up function
{
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter user name ( enter unique name )\n";
    gets(un);
    cout<<"Enter password\n";
    gets(pd);
    ofstream filout;
    filout.open("email",ios::app|ios::binary);
    if(!filout)
    {
        cout<<"cannot open file\n";
    }
    else
    {
        ino=-1;
        sno=-1;                  // initialising no. of sent and inbox msgs as 0 on regtrn

        filout.write((char *)&this,sizeof(this));
        filout.close();
    }
    cout<<"You are now registered. Plz login\n";
    getch();

}        // end of sign up or register func



void mail::signin()
{
    .
        .
        .
} // end of signin




void screen(void);
void signup(void);


void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char usrnm[25],pwd[25],s[25],c;
    int i;
m:
    clrscr();
    screen();
    gotoxy(30,4);
    c=getch();
    if(c=='i'||c=='I')               //if user opts to sign in
    {
        gotoxy(62,11);
        gets(usrnm);
        gotoxy(62,13);
        for(i=0;i< 25;i++)                   // getting password
        {
            if( i < 0)
                i=0;
            pwd[i]=getch();
            if(pwd[i]=='\b')
            {
                i-=2;
                cout<<"\b \b";
                continue;
            }

            if(pwd[i]=='\r')
                break;
            cout<<"*";
        }
        pwd[i]='\0';
        clrscr();              // pwd now contains password for sign in

        print();

        int f;
        {                       // local block

            mail obj;
            ifstream filein;
            filein.open("email",ios::in|ios::binary);    // to read records from file and authenticating the user
            if(!filein)
            {
                cout<<"Unable to open file to read\n";
            }
            else
            {
                filein.seekg(0);
                filein.read((char *)&obj,sizeof(obj));
                while(filein)
                {
                    if(strcmp(usrnm,obj.un)==0)
                    {
                        f=1;
                        if(strcmp(pwd,obj.pd)==0)
                        {
                            obj.signin();            // user authenticated. now transfering control
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout<<"wrong password\n";
                            getch();
                            break;
                        }
                    } // end of if
                    else
                    {
                    }
                    filein.read((char *)&obj,sizeof(obj));
                }               // end of while
                filein.close();
            } // end of else

        }


        if(f==0)
            cout<<"Wrong username or password\n";
        getch();
        goto m;
    }
    else if(c=='s'||c=='S')       // user opts to sign up
    {
        signup();
        getch();
        goto m;
    }
    else if(c=='e'||c=='E')       // user choose to exit
        exit(0);
    else
    {
        clrscr();
        cout<<"you have entered a wrong key. please check and try again\n";
        getch();
        goto m;
    }

}  //end of main


void signup()                   // sign up function
{
    int t;
    clrscr();
    {
        mail obj;
        ifstream filin;
        filin.open("user.txt",ios::ate);      // a file to store the no. of currently registered user. THIS IS FOR FUTURE USE
        if(!filin)
        {
            cout<<"cannot open file\n";
        }
        else
        {
            filin.seekg(0);
            filin>>t;
        }
        filin.close();
        user=t;
        ++user;                     // incrementing no. users

        ofstream filout;
        filout.open("user.txt",ios::out);
        if(!filout)
        {
            cout<<"cannot open file\n";
        }
        else
        {
            filout.seekp(0);
            filout<<user;                 //Updating user
        }
        filin.close();
        obj.reg();

    }  // end of block

    return;

}       // end of sign up



void screen()                // function for login screen
{
    .
        .
}
```

Full code:

```
#include<fstream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<process.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int user;           // to keep a track of no. of users

class mail
{
public:
    char un[25];             // user name
    char pd[25];             // passsword
    int ino;                 // no. of inbox messages
    int sno;                 //no.of sent messags
    char isbj[25][25];
    char ssbj[25][25];
    char imsg[25][50];
    char smsg[25][50];       // character array to store inbox and sent messages respecvly
    void reg();             // func to sign up
    void signin();
    mail()
    {
    }
    ~mail()
    {
    }
};

void print();
void print()                     // for testing. retrieving data in the file
{
    mail o;
    cout<<"\nRunning print func();";

    ifstream filein;
    filein.open("email",ios::in|ios::binary);
    if(!filein)
    {
        cout<<"Unable to open file to read\n";
    }
    else
    {
        filein.seekg(0);
        filein.read((char *)&o,sizeof(o));
        while(filein)
        {
            puts(o.un);
            puts(o.pd);
            cout<<o.ino<<"  "<<o.sno;
            filein.read((char *)&o,sizeof(o));
        }
        getch();
    }
}


void mail::reg()                      // sign up function
{
    clrscr();
    cout<<"Enter user name ( enter unique name )\n";
    gets(un);
    cout<<"Enter password\n";
    gets(pd);
    ofstream filout;
    filout.open("email",ios::app|ios::binary);
    if(!filout)
    {
        cout<<"cannot open file\n";
    }
    else
    {
        ino=-1;
        sno=-1;                  // initialising no. of sent and inbox msgs as 0 on regtrn

        filout.write((char *)&this,sizeof(this));
        filout.close();
    }
    cout<<"You are now registered. Plz login\n";
    getch();

}        // end of sign up or register func



void mail::signin()
{
    int f,i;
    char subj[25],message[50],usrnm[25];    // temporary varibles to store subject,message and username

start:
    clrscr();
    cout<<"1.compose \n2.inbox \n3.Sent\n4.logout";
    cout<<"\nEnter ur choice\n";
    int ch;
    cin>>ch;

    switch(ch)
    {

    case 1:                                       // switch for compose message
        cout<<"enter username\n";
        gets(usrnm);
        {            // beginning of local loop
            mail temp;

            ifstream filein;
            filein.open("email",ios::in|ios::binary);
            if(!filein)
            {
                cout<<"Unable to open file to read\n";
            }
            else
            {
                filein.read((char *)&temp,sizeof(temp));
                while(filein)
                {
                    if(strcmp(usrnm,temp.un)==0)
                    {
                        cout<<" User name valid\n";
                        f=1;
                        cout<<"Enter subject\n";
                        gets(subj);
                        cout<<"Enter message\n";
                        gets(message);
                        temp.ino++;
                        strcpy(temp.isbj[temp.ino],subj);
                        strcpy(temp.imsg[temp.ino],message);  // copying message to recepient inbox

                        sno++;
                        strcpy(ssbj[sno],subj);
                        strcpy(smsg[sno],message);  // copying messages to sender sent folder

                        cout<<"Your message has been sent successfully\n";
                        break;
                    }
                    else      // to avoid if else mismatch
                    {
                    }
                    filein.read((char *)&temp,sizeof(temp));
                }               // end of while
            }
            filein.close();


            mail temp1;

            long pos;                  // below code modifies current users object
            fstream fio("email",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
            pos=fio.tellg();
            fio.read((char*)&temp1,sizeof(temp1));
            while(fio)
            {
                if(strcmp(un,temp1.un)==0)
                {
                    fio.seekg(pos);
                    fio.write((char*)&this,sizeof(this));
                    break;
                }
                pos=fio.tellg();
                fio.read((char*)&temp1,sizeof(temp1));
            }   //end of while
            fio.close();

            mail temp2;               // below code modifies recipients object

            fio.open("email",ios::in|ios::out|ios::binary);
            pos=fio.tellg();
            fio.read((char*)&temp2,sizeof(temp2));
            while(fio)
            {
                if(strcmp(temp.un,temp2.un)==0)
                {
                    fio.seekg(pos);
                    fio.write((char*)&temp,sizeof(temp));
                    break;
                }
                pos=fio.tellg();
                fio.read((char*)&temp2,sizeof(temp2));
            } // end of while
            fio.close();
        } // end of block

        if(f==0)
            cout<<"invalid user. Please enter a valid user name\n";
        getch();
        break;

    case 2:
        if(ino<0)
            cout<<"There are no messages in your inbox\n";
        else
        {
            for(i=0;i<=ino;i++)
            {
                cout<<"\nMessage "<<i+1<<"\n";   // printing inbox messages
                puts(isbj[i]);
                puts(imsg[i]);
            }
        }
        getch();
        break;

    case 3:
        if(sno<0)
            cout<<"There are no sent messages\n";
        else
        {
            for(i=0;i<=sno;i++)
            {
                cout<<"\nMessage "<<i+1<<"\n";      // printing sent messages
                puts(ssbj[i]);
                puts(smsg[i]);
            }
        }
        getch();
        break;

    case 4:
        cout<<"Logout sucess\n";
        return;

    default : cout<<"wrong choice\n";

    } // end of switch

    goto start;

} // end of signin




void screen(void);
void signup(void);


void main()
{
    clrscr();
    char usrnm[25],pwd[25],s[25],c;
    int i;
m:
    clrscr();
    screen();
    gotoxy(30,4);
    c=getch();
    if(c=='i'||c=='I')               //if user opts to sign in
    {
        gotoxy(62,11);
        gets(usrnm);
        gotoxy(62,13);
        for(i=0;i< 25;i++)                   // getting password
        {
            if( i < 0)
                i=0;
            pwd[i]=getch();
            if(pwd[i]=='\b')
            {
                i-=2;
                cout<<"\b \b";
                continue;
            }

            if(pwd[i]=='\r')
                break;
            cout<<"*";
        }
        pwd[i]='\0';
        clrscr();              // pwd now contains password for sign in

        print();

        int f;
        {                       // local block

            mail obj;
            ifstream filein;
            filein.open("email",ios::in|ios::binary);    // to read records from file and authenticating the user
            if(!filein)
            {
                cout<<"Unable to open file to read\n";
            }
            else
            {
                filein.seekg(0);
                filein.read((char *)&obj,sizeof(obj));
                while(filein)
                {
                    if(strcmp(usrnm,obj.un)==0)
                    {
                        f=1;
                        if(strcmp(pwd,obj.pd)==0)
                        {
                            obj.signin();            // user authenticated. now transfering control
                            break;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            cout<<"wrong password\n";
                            getch();
                            break;
                        }
                    } // end of if
                    else
                    {
                    }
                    filein.read((char *)&obj,sizeof(obj));
                }               // end of while
                filein.close();
            } // end of else

        }


        if(f==0)
            cout<<"Wrong username or password\n";
        getch();
        goto m;
    }
    else if(c=='s'||c=='S')       // user opts to sign up
    {
        signup();
        getch();
        goto m;
    }
    else if(c=='e'||c=='E')       // user choose to exit
        exit(0);
    else
    {
        clrscr();
        cout<<"you have entered a wrong key. please check and try again\n";
        getch();
        goto m;
    }

}  //end of main


void signup()                   // sign up function
{
    int t;
    clrscr();
    {
        mail obj;
        ifstream filin;
        filin.open("user.txt",ios::ate);      // a file to store the no. of currently registered user. THIS IS FOR FUTURE USE
        if(!filin)
        {
            cout<<"cannot open file\n";
        }
        else
        {
            filin.seekg(0);
            filin>>t;
        }
        filin.close();
        user=t;
        ++user;                     // incrementing no. users

        ofstream filout;
        filout.open("user.txt",ios::out);
        if(!filout)
        {
            cout<<"cannot open file\n";
        }
        else
        {
            filout.seekp(0);
            filout<<user;                 //Updating user
        }
        filin.close();
        obj.reg();

    }  // end of block

    return;

}       // end of sign up



void screen()                // function for login screen
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<80;i++)
        cout<<"*";
    cout<<" SuperMail                             New to SuperMial ? Create an Account     ";
    for(i=0;i<80;i++)
        cout<<"*";
    cout<<" Press S To Sign up                    Already have a account Press I to sign in";
    for(i=0;i<80;i++)
        cout<<"-";
    gotoxy(1,6);
    cout<<"\n\n\n\n Super mail is built on the idea that \n it can be more intuitive,efficient and \n useful and may be even fun:\n\n Lots of space\n\n Less spam";
    gotoxy(1,22);
    for(i=0;i<80;i++)
        cout<<"-";
    gotoxy(32,23);
    cout<<"PRESS E TO EXIT";
    gotoxy(1,24);
    for(i=0;i<80;i++)
        cout<<"-";
    gotoxy(50,10);
    cout<<"-------------------------------";
    gotoxy(50,11);
    cout<<"| USERNAME :                  |";
    gotoxy(50,12);
    cout<<"-------------------------------";
    gotoxy(50,13);
    cout<<"| PASSWORD :                  |";
    gotoxy(50,14);
    cout<<"-------------------------------";
}
```

Comment: why do you not use c++ strings as opposed to the headaches char arrays will give you? I dont quite understand your method of using old C concepts

Comment: Try to *break your problem down*, post *minimal code* and omit information that is irrelevant to the problem. As it stands, your question and the posted code is way too long.

Comment: argh! "goto start;" When I see things like this in C or C++ code, I just feel like running very far away...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't read through all the code but one problem is

```
filout.write((char *)&this,sizeof(this));
```

`this` is a pointer so the above code writes the address of your class instance to file.  You could write out all class members using

```
filout.write((char*)this,sizeof(*this));
```

I expect this will also write out some data you don't want/need such as address of v-table.  You might be better off explicitly persisting the class members you care about instead.

Comment: Thanks let me compile it again

Comment: Wow thank you so much. It works. Now i can login and send messages. I have not fully tested it , but i want to thank you first. thanks again

Comment: Glad to hear it works; thanks for accepting my answer.  For future questions, can you please consider the various bits of feedback your received earlier?  The folks here are generally very helpful but you'll get the best response when you ask as small and specific a question as possible.

Comment: Yes i definitely will. I didnt know how to ask properly in these forum. Now i got it and will do the needful. Currently iam storing my messages in a statically allocated 2d array. Its difficult to implement message delete functionality in this. Also i like to provide unlimited space for storing messages. The one way i think about it is creating a structure inside the class and dynamically creating new object as needed. But im not exact about it. Will it work ? Should i be able to write objects into file the same way if i wrote a structure inside a class. Is it possible ? Thanks

Comment: Read up on std::vector for a standard way of storing a varying number of objects.  It will be possible to define a vector of structs and create code to write the struct to and read it from file.  Have a go at this then post further questions if you can't make it work :-)